# Sitecore Admin login page loads forever with nothing to display

Tags: sitecore-client

I am trying to setup my Sitecore project in my new laptop with Windows 10 using Sitecore Instance Manager (SIM). I am also using their Solr add-on option. Everything is marked as "DONE" in the SIM setup.

However, when I am trying to access my sitecore/login page it is just loading forever. I have provided necessary "Full Control" permissions to IUSR, NETWORK SERVICE and IIS_IUSRS accounts for the deploy folder. And of-course to the App pool instance.

Let me know where I missed the things

-EDIT-

Here is my log, which is showing some error related to Analytics, but I am sure this shouldn't be a problem or is it ?

> 10860 14:15:21 ERROR Exception when executing agent
>   aggregation/automationAggreg ator Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException Message: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Source: Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.RangeScheduler.MongoDbRangeMap2.TryLockRange(WorkerHand
>   le worker, DateTime leaseExpiration, RangeHandle& range)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Core.RangeScheduler.RangeMapWorkScheduler2`1.TryLockRan
>   ge(WorkScheduler`1& context)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Core.RangeScheduler.RangeMapWorkScheduler2`1.GetNextRan
>   ge(WorkScheduler`1& context)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Core.RangeScheduler.RangeMapWorkScheduler2`1.TryGetNext
>   (TKey& item)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Aggregation.AutomationWorkDispatcher.TryGetN
>   ext(AutomationWorkItem& workItem)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Aggregation.Data.Processing.AggregatorAgent.
>   Execute()    at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()
>
> 8232 14:15:22 ERROR Exception when executing agent
>   aggregation/automationAggrega tor Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException Message: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Source: Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.RangeScheduler.MongoDbRangeMap2.TryLockRange(WorkerHand
>   le worker, DateTime leaseExpiration, RangeHandle& range)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Core.RangeScheduler.RangeMapWorkScheduler2`1.TryLockRan
>   ge(WorkScheduler`1& context)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Core.RangeScheduler.RangeMapWorkScheduler2`1.GetNextRan
>   ge(WorkScheduler`1& context)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Core.RangeScheduler.RangeMapWorkScheduler2`1.TryGetNext
>   (TKey& item)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Aggregation.AutomationWorkDispatcher.TryGetN
>   ext(AutomationWorkItem& workItem)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Aggregation.Data.Processing.AggregatorAgent.
>   Execute()    at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

Comment: Post your log, please.

Comment: Make sure mongoDB service is running. If you don't have mongoDB, just disable the analytics and see if the page still takes time to load

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Thank you. This worked. But I was not sure this could be the reason. I have saw my previous applications worked without MongoDb in place. Thanks anyways. Can you please have this comment as answer so I can mark it ?

Comment: @SeenuKuppan I have added the answer

Comment: For me, Restarting MongoDB service did not worked. Please try restart IIS Server and Mongo Service both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is related to connection to the MongoDB database. You need to make sure that the MongoDB service is on.

If ever you do not intend to use MongoDB, you need to disable the Sitecore Analytics in the config file from the `Include` folder.